# White space between anchor tags

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain me why there is white space between anchor tags and how I can remove it without using negative values in e.g. margin property?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5khf8ys7/)

```css
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #6BBFDB solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6BBFDB;
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}

a:visited {
  color: #6BBFDB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">What is this whitespace? -&gt;</a>
  <a href="#">&lt;- What is this whitespace?</a>
</div>
```

I have not seen this before tbh, maybe due to always wanting to have space between anchors, but this time I do not wish for space between anchors so that is why I stumbled upon this issue for the first time ever.

Comment: You have more solutions here https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because inline elements are sensitive to the white space in your code. You can just remove that:

```css
a
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #6BBFDB solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6BBFDB;
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a:hover
{
  background-color: #999;
}

a:visited
{
  color: #6BBFDB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="#">What is this whitespace? -&gt;</a><a href="#"> &lt;- What is this whitespace?</a>
</div>
```

You can also use an HTML comment to take up the space like `...</a><!-- --><a>`

```css
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #6BBFDB solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6BBFDB;
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}
a:visited {
  color: #6BBFDB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">What is this whitespace? -&gt;</a><!--
  --><a href="#"> &lt;- What is this whitespace?</a>
</div>
```

Another option is to set the font size to zero on the container and then restore it on the links:

```css
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #6BBFDB solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6BBFDB;
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}
a:visited {
  color: #6BBFDB;
}
.container {
  font-size:0;
}
.container a {
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">What is this whitespace? -&gt;</a>
  <a href="#"> &lt;- What is this whitespace?</a>
</div>
```

Finally (phew) you could just float the links left:

```css
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #6BBFDB solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6BBFDB;
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}
a:visited {
  color: #6BBFDB;
}
.container a {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">What is this whitespace? -&gt;</a>
  <a href="#"> &lt;- What is this whitespace?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is default for html float:left can be a solution with u.  css is

```
a
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #6BBFDB solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6BBFDB;
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float:left;
}

a:hover
{
  background-color: #999;
}

a:visited
{
  color: #6BBFDB;
}
```

Comment: If you need your container to maintain it's height while using this approach then you can add the class `.container:after { display:block; content: ''; height: 0; clear: both; }`.